# Angular.js -- use ng-show to show element only if other element is not disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an element that I would like to show only when another form element is NOT disabled.

```
<input ng-model="myModel">
```

None of the following work:

```
<div ng-show="myModel">
```

This will show if the input is disabled, as long as it has had a value set in the past.

```
<div ng-show="myModel.enabled">
<div ng-show="!myModel.disabled">
```

Those props don't seem to exist.

```
<div ng-show='!angular.element(po.vendor__contact).prop("disabled")'>
```

Thought that might work to ask jQuery if it's disabled, but it doesn't.

Is there any way to reference whether an element is enabled or not in an Angular directive? Can it be done by asking jQuery?

Thanks!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3197/

Answer (score 5):

I think your not using Angular the right way. You should not base the visibility of an element based on the state of another element.

Both elements should depend on the model:

```
<input ng-model="myModel" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
<div ng-hide="isDisabled">
```

Basically, view reflects the model, don't inspect the DOM, and don't use jQuery. Also you can use `ng-hide` instead of ng-show and !

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3198/

Comment: I take your point. However, I am working on an existing application of someone else's design, where all the data is stored not in a model, but in the state of the form inputs on the page. So the only information available as to whether this div should be shown is the state of some other elements on the page.

Comment: You can bind the form to a model, so then you can use it, see my fiddle

Comment: Thanks, I do understand how to use ng-show/hide based on another model. The problem is that in this particular situation, the only good information I have about whether my div should be shown or not is whether or not some input is enabled. Therefore I am just interested in finding out how to write a directive that checks the enabled/disabled state of another element (although I appreciate the advice about keeping state in a model instead of in form elements, that is definitely sound advice.)